# PHP code supposed to check a file for an ID not working correctly

Tags: php, foreach

So I'm working on a PHP app receiving a student ID from an input and searching through a file to find if the ID is present or not. If it's present, the name of the student and whether hes present or not should be printed out, and if the ID doesn't exist, it should say that there are no students with this ID.
Here is an example of what the txt file looks like:

```
1234|Sally Simon|1 
4321|Larry Lonbottom|0 
7364|Hannah Harrow|1
```

I made a solution and tested it, but it prints out a student name even when the ID I enter is false. Could someone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$student=$_GET["student"];
$lines = file('students.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line){
    $var = explode("|", $line);

}

    if($student == $var[0] || $var[2] == "1"){
        echo "$var[1]($var[0]): has signed up";
    }else if($student == $var[0] || $var[2] == "0"){
        echo "$var[1]($var[0]): hasn't signed up";
    }else{
        echo "No students with that id!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's a dummy app, I'm just getting started on php @B001ᛦ

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "and" (`&&`) comparison instead of "or" (`||`)?

Comment: Couldn't you just sanitise the lines of text from the  and get it to return only numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OPs said you need to change your conditional logic (if elses) and place it within the foreach loop (i.e. before the foreach's closing `}`.

**However:** ([php.net file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)) "*Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.*" so **you have to remove the EOL/NL marker** (invisible whitespace) from $var[2]. This can be achieved changing your file function to `file('students.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)` however it is probably best to use `trim` as per example below.

It may help simplify things for you if you get rid of else conditions. try this:

```
<?php 
$student=trim($_GET["student"]);  // should also check and exit if ! digits 
$lines = file('students.txt');
$isRegistered = array( "hasn't signed up", "has signed up");
$invalidID = TRUE;

foreach ($lines as $line){   
    $var = explode("|", $line);
    if( $student == trim($var[0]) ) {
        echo "$var[1]($var[0]): " . $isRegistered[ trim($var[2]) ];
        $invalidID = FALSE;
        break; // prevent unnecessary processing, exit foreach loop
    }
}         
if ( $invalidID ) echo "No students with that id!";
?>
```

Note: the above assumes file only contains valid content.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your `$var` will always have the last line in the file, wrap everything with the `foreach`;

2) You should use `&&` instead of `||`

EDIT: updated code

```
   <?php 
    $student=$_GET["student"];
    $lines = file('students.txt');
    $missing = true;

    foreach ($lines as $line){
        $var = explode("|", $line);
        if($student == $var[0]){
             $missing = false;
             if($var[2] == "1"){
               echo "$var[1]($var[0]): has signed up";
             }else if($var[2] == "0"){
               echo "$var[1]($var[0]): hasn't signed up";
             }
        }
    }
    if($missing){
       echo "No students with that id!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not seeming to work correctly for me. It prints out the student details or the no student present line as many times as there are students on the file.

Comment: Add a `break;` after each `echo`.

Comment: Would there ever be more than one entry with the same id? If so, you might not get the results you are expecting.

Comment: I think I have another issue in the code, like one of the conditions is not working correctly. That's why it would always give me a student with the || but never with the && .

Comment: @AmmoPT thank you, again there is an issue since it's not printing anything if the ID is correct

Comment: @n_at Can you `echo` the `$student` and `$var[0]` variables after this line `$var = explode("|", $line);` ? To make sure everything is being set up correctly.

Comment: yeah it echoes it fine there.

Comment: @n_at Check Rook's comment regarding sanitizing your strings.

Comment: @n_at Do a `var_dump` instead of the `echo` to make 100% sure it's not extra whitespace comming from the file. Because **the data file you pasted will indeed have an extra whitespace on the id of the first two records**, the third and last one is fine. Try that ID.

Comment: @n_at I meant the third field (has signed up / has not signed up), not the ID sorry. For the first and second records will be "1 " and "0 " thus failing the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Put the if statements inside the loop since you want to use those conditionals with every line.

(2) You are using logical 'or' operators. This means that only one of the conditions for that line need to be met. 
This is what you are saying

```
if $student == $var[0] OR if $var[2] == 1
```

So regardless of what ID you enter, you always match the 0 or 1 condition.

Use the `&&` operator instead of `||` if you need **both** conditions to be met instead of just one of the two.

(3) By using the `==` operator, the string will have to match with the value you are looking for *exactly*. You might have spaces in `$student` or there might be additional character in between the `|`. Just to air on the side of caution, remove all chances of there being hidden whitespace with your variables.

Do this: `$student[0] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $student[0]);` and do that with `var[0]` and `var[2]` as well. Do this before you run them through the `if` statements but still inside the loop.

[Here is a link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) that talks about logical operators in php. It might be nice to use as a reference for future conditional statements that you need to build!

[This link explains](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) what you are doing to these values with `preg_replace`. It becomes very handy when you need to remove characters from a string that otherwise might difficult to deal with.

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't actually know that! Thank you! I was actually thinking both these operators were used for the same thing. However, now the problem is that it never finds the student even if the ID is correct.

Comment: I've updated my answer! You might be having a problem with whitespace being in one of your variables and therefor not having identical strings(I wonder if it is coming from `$student`). Either remove the potential whitespace or see if the strings in the txt file are similar rather than identical to the `$student` variable.

Comment: Can also use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), might be simpler for this particular case.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, but I'm really not sure this is the case since when I echo the vars they seem just fine, I think Im either doing something wrong in the loop or in the if statement.

Comment: Is `student` and integer or a string? `$var[0]` is a string. Make sure the types match. Use `echo gettype($student);` to see the value type. If it doesn't say string, you need to convert it to a string.